# Server needs postgres even though I use sqlserver on it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, postgresql, deployment, capistrano

I deploy with Capistrano: `cap int deploy`.

Then, I have this as my `database.yml` file

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

sqlserver: &sqlserver
  adapter: sqlserver
  timeout: 5000
  database: Consumer
  username: '<%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>'
  password: '<%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>'

development:
  <<: *default
  database: some_dev_db

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: some_test_db

int:
  <<: *sqlserver
  host: some_int_db
```

my Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.1'

gem 'rails-api'

gem 'tiny_tds'
gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', git: 'https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter'

gem 'unicorn'

gem 'active_model_serializers'

gem 'figaro'

gem 'faker'

gem 'spring', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pry-nav'
  gem 'pg'
end

group :deployment do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'hipchat'
end
```

I tried doing stuff initially after running `bundle install` on my server, but I got an error that it needed `gem pg 0.17.1`. Then, I did `bundle install --without development test` because I DON'T NEED PG on the server.

I continue to get the fact that my server needs pg even when I do things like `bundle exec RAILS_ENV=INT rake db:migrate` and try to open the int environment console. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try change it

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

to this

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlserver
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Work for me.